# Detectar si cambio el valor de un key en la siguiente vuelta del foreach?

Tags: php, array, foreach

Necesito averiguar si el valor de un key cambia el la siguiente vuelta

Ej:

```
if($manzanas[$key]['cantidad'] == $manzanas[$key + 1]['cantidad']){
   echo 'La cantidad de manzanas es la misma';
} else {
   echo 'La cantidad de manzanas cambio';
}
```

Asi no funciona y no encuentro la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: Recomido que el código sea legible y que coloque todo el código con el forEach

Comment: podrias agregar el arreglo con el que estas probando?? tambien necesitamos lo que te retorna y lo que quieres que te retorne

Answer (score -2):

Supongo que te tira un error al intentar buscar `'cantidad'` dentro de una `$key` inexistente, como estás haciendo un `$key + 1`, va a llegar un punto en donde el siguiente no existe y por ende te imprime un error.
Para solucionarlo deberías agregarle una comprobación más antes de preguntar si el siguiente es igual:

```
if (isset($manzanas[$key + 1]) && $manzanas[$key]['cantidad'] == $manzanas[$key + 1]['cantidad']) {
   echo 'La cantidad de manzanas es la misma';
} else {
   echo 'La cantidad de manzanas cambio';
}
```

Comment: si escribes supongo, en lo que busca creo que primero le debes pedir mas informacion y luego escribir la respuesta, yo no veo un ejemplo del array al que quiere